# MYSQL Query - Get the users that are not equal to the users I am following

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the users I am not following and that isn't equal to me.

So far I have got this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            u.id,
            u.username,
            u.profileImage,
            u.fullname,
            u.coverImage,
            u.bio,
            a.uuid,
            a.type
            FROM USERS u
            JOIN Activity a
            WHERE NOT u.id = 145
            AND a.id = 145
            AND type = 'follow'
```

145 is the current user.

I store following's in the Activity table, So I Don't want to get the users that are equal to the IdOtherUser in the row where id = 145.

When I follow someone it would be like this:

Id = 145(me)

IdOtherUser = 86(other person I follow, who I don't want to get from USERS table.)

type = 'follow'(type of action)

I am successfully getting all the users that aren't equal to me(145) but cannot seem to get the users that are equal to the people I follow!

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**fiddle**

[I want to get the users that is not equal to 123(current user, and the people he is following user(145))](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45682)

Comment: No JOIN condition? Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: provide the table structures and their foreign key

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT 
            u.id,
            u.username,
            u.profileImage,
            u.fullname,
            u.coverImage,
            u.bio,
            a.uuid,
            a.type
            FROM USERS u
            JOIN Activity a
            ON a.IdOtherUser = u.id
            AND a.id = 145
            AND type = 'follow'` I just comment it cause I am not sure

Comment: @jarlh added fiddle

Comment: @NewbeeDev added fiddle

Comment: @NewbeeDev and that is getting the users I follow

Comment: Okay hahhahaha lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to accomplish the expected outcome. They are all based on using a subquery to determine if a user is followed by a given user. You can have this subquery as a derived table (in the `from` clause), or in a `not in()` or [not exists()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) operator. I'll show you an example for the `not exists()` operator because it does not have to pull data from the users table, it merely checks if you have a record corresponding to the where criteria

```
select *
from users u1
where u1.id<>145  --not me
    and not exists (select 1
                    from activity a
                    where a.id=145 --users I follow
                        and a.IdOtherUser=u1.id
                        and a.type='follow')
```

Comment: Just join the users table on the posts table using the users' id. But this should be a separate question.